# Is the regular expression enough or I need some more checks?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, security

I have a search from, When the user type a keyword, The script looks for that keyword in the Database:

```
<form method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="q" id="keyword" placeholder="Enter a keyword" > 
    <input type="submit" value="Search" >
</form>
```

After the form is submitted I check the following:

```
//Check is the form is submitted.
if( isset($_GET['q']) ){

    //Assign the submitted keyword to a variable.
    $query = $_GET['q'];

    //Check if the keyword is empty.
    if(!empty($query)){

        //Check if the keyword matches the pattern.
        //The pattern checks that the keyword contains characters from any language and maybe there are spaces between them.
        $pattern = "~^\p{L}[\p{L}\p{M}\h()]*$~u";

        //If the keyword matches the pattern.
        if(preg_match($pattern, $query)){

            //Fetch data from the Database.
            $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title OR description LIKE  :s LIMIT 5');
            $stmt->bindValue(':s', '%' . $query . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
            $posts = $stmt->fetchAll();

        }
    }
```

Are these checks enough to stop SQL injection and the other attacks?

Or I need to create a blacklist? Or check something else?

Comment: The fact that you're binding the value to a statement is enough to prevent SQL injection - anything else is probably superfluous.

Comment: If you output `$query` to the browser later you could be open to XSS injections. Unrelated but `title OR description LIKE` works?

Comment: @user3783243, Like inserting the keyword `$query` in the search input? Is there is something about `title OR description LIKE`?

Comment: `title OR description LIKE` does not work like youd think it does. It merely states that `title` must exist (not null, a truthy value), OR `description like something`. So... I doubt the results will be expected behavior in that regard.

Comment: If you later do `<input type="text" value="<?php echo $query;?>">` you'd be open to XSS injection because a `"` would close the attribute then the rest of the input will go to the DOM e.g. `" onclick="alert('injected')"`.

Comment: If you want the `title` or `post` to contain the term do a `concat` with a space separator (or some unique separator). `concat(title, ' ', description) LIKE  :s`

Comment: @user3783243, I don't understand how that would be opened to XSS(cross site scripting), Would that be saved or what?

Comment: @user3783243, Stackoverflow itself does that and print the search input value

Comment: The escape it. Put the pieces together, it'd become `<input type="text" value="" onclick="alert('injected')" ">` so an `onclick` would be added.

Comment: But that `onclick="alert('injected')" ">` would be added to the DB and shown to all the other users or just that user who enter that code?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using parameterized query you don't need regular expression at all. The difference between a parameterized query and just concat the parameter is how the query is executed in the end. For example:

```
query q = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE people.age =" + userInput;
```

That way the query will be concatenated and then executed purely. In your case you are are passing your user input as a parameter:

```
query q = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title OR description LIKE  :s LIMIT 5"
```

Which will not concatenate the quarry directly it will compare the value of the parameter `s`. Make sure you always use a parameterized query as it's a good practice and much safer approach

Comment: Does that include `$stmt->execute( [$query] )` ? or just ` $stmt->bindValue` ?

Comment: @Dan That's the way your query is going to be executed. The binding itself is just providing the parameter that your query is expecting in order to be executable. I hope that was useful.

Comment: So if there is no `bindValue` there is no problem?

Comment: @Dan no, binding itself is the main thing that prevent your code from SQL injections.

Comment: What if there are more that one variable? Should I bind all of them like `$stmt->bindValue(':s', '%' . $query . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR); $stmt->bindValue(':a', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);`?

Comment: @Dan yes if your query is expecting two parameters